# group the array of objects with similar properties and get result with concatenated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, loops, object

i have this array of object as follows

```
let data = [
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_status.com", "_verify.com" ] },
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_result.com"] },
    { "id": "15", "values": [ "_integrate.com"] }
]
```

If you notice, array of object has 2 objects with the same id `12` and it has 3 variables in `values` combined together. Similarly id `15` has only one values variable.

How do i group them together and accumulate the values property in one array. I want to achieve below result.

```
let result = [
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_status.com", "_verify.com", "_result.com" ] },
    { "id": "15", "values": [ "_integrate.com"] }
]
```

can someone let me know how to achieve this. i did search online regarding iteration of array of objects but this is a very unique and different example and i could not find anything close to solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`reduce`](https://%5B%60Array#reduce%60%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) by iterating through the `data` array.
For each object in the array, check if an entry for the `id` already exists in the accumulator object (`acc`):

- If not, create a new entry with an empty values array.
- If yes, concatenate the values array of the current object to the existing values array in the accumulator.

Finally use [`Object.values()`](https://%5B%60Object#values%60%5D(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)) to extract the accumulated values as an array and assign it to the result variable

```js
let data = [
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_status.com", "_verify.com" ] },
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_result.com"] },
    { "id": "15", "values": [ "_integrate.com"] }
];

let result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, {id, values}) => {
    if (!acc[id]) {
        acc[id] = { id, values: [] };
    }
    acc[id].values = acc[id].values.concat(values);
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the traditional for loop to create a new array of result like this. Let me know if this works

```
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let currentObj = data[i];
    let foundIndex = result.findIndex(item => item.id === currentObj.id);

    if (foundIndex > -1) {
        result[foundIndex].values.push(...currentObj.values);
    } else {
        result.push({ 
            id: currentObj.id, 
            values: [...currentObj.values] 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also `Object.groupBy` the `id`'s and then `map()` the objects to combine the `values`

```js
let data = [
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_status.com", "_verify.com" ] },
    { "id": "12", "values": [ "_result.com"] },
    { "id": "15", "values": [ "_integrate.com"] }
]

const grouped = Object.groupBy(data, s => s.id);
const combined = Object.keys(grouped).map(id => (
    { id, values: grouped[id].flatMap(f => f.values) }
));

console.log(combined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group only by `id` as *key* and `values` as *value*. For getting the wanted stucture map the `id`/`values` as object.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: "12", values: ["_status.com", "_verify.com"] }, { id: "12", values: ["_result.com"] }, { id: "15", values: ["_integrate.com"] }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { id, values }) => m.set(id, [...(m.get(id) || []), ...values]), new Map),
        ([id, values]) => ({ id, values })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```